# Swift indexOf inconsistent behavior

Tags: arrays, swift, indexof, nsobject, equatable

It seems that I've facing inconsistent behavior with Swift's `indexOf` function.

There are two `indexOf` functions in Swift:
1. The first one takes `Equatable` as an argument: `array.indexOf(obj)`
2. The second takes matching closure as an argument: `array.indexOf{$0 == obj}`

I have an `NSObject` subclass for which `==` operator is defined, i.e. it conforms to `Equatable`, therefore, I assume both function to work exactly the same (with closure in example).

However, the `1st` method behaves inconsistently, in particular it returns `nil` when being invoked with object, instance of which is not present in array.

To illustrate issue, I provide example code with comments:

```
class EqObj: NSObject {
  let value: Int
  init(value: Int) {
    self.value = value
  }
}

func ==(lhs: EqObj, rhs: EqObj) -> Bool{
  return lhs.value == rhs.value
}

var array = [Obj(value: 1), Obj(value: 3), Obj(value: 5)]
var object = Obj(value: 5)

// returns nil, should return 2 - incorrect
array.indexOf(object) // Instance is not present
// returns 2, correct
array.indexOf(array.last!) // Instance is present
// returns 2, correct
array.indexOf{$0 == object} // Instance is not present, predicate
// returns non-empty array, correct
array.filter{$0 == object} // Instance is not present, predicate
```

The issue is reproducible only with `NSObject` subclasses. When I change `Obj: NSObject` to `Obj: Equatable` method `indexOf()` works exactly as expected, i.e. returns `2`.

The question is whether this can be considered a bug?

My assumption is that `array.indexOf(object)` invokes `isEqual` method of `NSObject` and not my overloaded `==` operator.

**My solution:**
I use `array.indexOf{$0 == object}`

Comment: How is `Obj` defined?

Comment: why do you think indexOf should use your overloaded operator? it is not a bug

Comment: @Lu_ because `indexOf()` operates on `Equatable`. The other `indexOf{}` works on any type and takes closure to compare two instances.

Comment: @appzYourLife just `EqObj: NSObject` (inconsistent behavior) or `EqObj: Equatable` (expected behavior)

Comment: You listed 4 examples, please add the declaration of `Obj` used for each example

Comment: @appzYourLife done

Comment: *"My assumption is that array.indexOf(object) invokes isEqual method of NSObject"* – Indeed it does, for NSObject subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

First of all with this definition I am getting different results

```
class Obj: NSObject {
    let value: Int

    init(value:Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Obj, rhs: Obj) -> Bool{
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}

var array = [Obj(value: 1), Obj(value: 3), Obj(value: 5)]
var object = Obj(value: 5)
```

here they are

[image]

You can read below the reasons after each result

### Result #1

```
array.indexOf(object) // nil
```

> In this case the isEqual method is used, so you are just comparing memory address. And since the `object` var references an object **NOT** inside the array, you get `nil` as result

### Result #2

```
array.indexOf(array.last!) // 2
```

> Again `isEqual` is used. However here you are passing to `indexOf` the reference to the last object in the array so it works.

### Result #3

```
array.indexOf { $0 == object } // 2
```

> Here you are explicitly using the `==` operator you defined so the `value` property is used.

### Result #4

```
array.filter { $0 == object } // [{NSObject, value 5}]
```

> Again the `==` operator is used and then the `value` property is used to check for equality.

Comment: How are the results differ from mine? They're exactly the same.

Comment: Result 3: you say instance is not present while I am getting the index 2. Result 4: you say instance is not present while I am getting the filtered array

Comment: I mean the particular instance of object is not present in array to be checked. It is a separate instance created in `var object = Object(value: 5)`. The results are listed above each line of code.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy: Then we get the same results, and you can find the reasons in my answer.